# Sending mail based on html file data using mailx in linux

Tags: unix, mailx

I have a html file with below data which I need to send mail from my linux system (not as an attachment:

```
> cat  mailingHtml.html
To:test.abc@gmail.com
Subject: ******Test Mail *******
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"
<html>
<body style="font-family:Courier New;font-size:14">
<p> Hi ... </html>
```

Below 'sendmail' command is working fine and I am receiving mail.

```
cat  mailingHtml.html |sendmail -table
```

But rather than using sendmail, I need to use 'mailx' now. I tried below, but no luck:

```
> mailx -a 'Content-Type: text/html' -s "my subject" test.abc@gmail.com <mailingHtml.html
Content-Type: text/html: No such file or directory

> mailx <mailingHtml.html
No mail for abc@gmail.com
```

Could someone please help me?